# How to solve error `You have specified an invalid column ordinal`

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I am getting the following error:

> You have specified an invalid column ordinal

I already checked the column number in my database and I know it's right. Here's my code:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
{

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtboxID.Text);
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        int size = dr.GetInt32(3);
        int quantity = dr.GetInt32(4);
        string variant = dr.GetString(2);

        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows
           .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
           .Where(r => (r.Cells["variant_name"].Value.ToString().Equals(variant) && r.Cells["size"].Value.Equals(size)))
           .First();

        row.Cells["quantity"].Value = quantity;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error on this line -> `int size = dr.GetInt32(3);`

Comment: In which of these lines do you get this?

Comment: Can you show the code where `dr` is instantiated?  Based on the error is sounds like there may not be any rows in it, or you didn't call `dr.Read` on it.

Comment: @Tim. I've updated the code I've already included the code where `dr` is instantiated.

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning results?  Have you run the query in SQL Server (or whatever your SQL of choice is)?

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure if its returning results. Anyway, how would I know?

Comment: Based on your error, I'd say it's returning results other than what you expected.  It looks like you're using `MySQL` - I believe there's a GUI control panel that you can run the query in to see if it gives results.  Can you post your query and the table structure?  The query is returning something, otherwise the `while` loop would never be entered.

Comment: @Tim Here is the query `string query = "SELECT variant_name, size,          quantity                                                                                                    FROM tblOrder_Products                                                                                                          WHERE order_ID=@ID";`

Comment: Your ordinals are off - variant should be 0, size should be 1 and quantity should be 2.  The ordinal is 0 based.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30662/discussion-between-harvey-and-tim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning three columns, and the column ordinal is 0 based, so your ordinals would be 0, 1, and 2, like this:

```
int size = dr.GetInt32(1);
int quantity = dr.GetInt32(2);
string variant = dr.GetString(0);
```

As your query returns `variant_name`, `size` and `quantity` in that order (0, 1, and 2).

Comment: Okay I know now. Because, at first I'm a little confuse if that ordinal is based on the column number in my database. Thank you again.